# helm-semantic-imenu doesn't identify pointers and references in C++ code

Tags: c++, semantic-mode, imenu

With `semantic-mode` enabled and reading a C++ source file in `cc-mode`, running `helm-semantic-or-imenu` correctly shows all the classes, variables and functions defined in that file. However, all the descriptions have the characters `&` and `*` missing. So, by simply looking at the entries shown in the `helm semantic/imenu` buffer, I can't tell the correct signatures. For example, a member variable defined as `const char* fileName` shows up as `const char fileName`. Is there some variable which would change this display behaviour?

EDIT : More information thanks to @TuDo - Both `semantic-ia-show-summary` and `helm-semantic-or-imenu` use `semantic-format-tag-summarize` to parse the tag info. However, the latter correctly outputs `const char* fileName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a buffer with only the line `const char* fileName` as above, running `(semantic-fetch-tags)` returns this tag that gives back `char` as type:

```
(("filename" variable (:pointer 1 :constant-flag t :type "char") nil #<overlay from 1 to 22 in 03-095759.c>))
```

The type is "char", although it has the attribute `:pointer 1` to denote the level of pointer. `helm-semantic` does not account for this attribute, so I will try to update it and create a PR for Helm to fix this.

**EDIT**: But then, the Helm function uses `semantic-format-tag-summarize` to format tag for displaying in Helm, so this is a bug in Semantic itself for not returning correct original appearance of tag. I will report this to CEDET maintainer.

**EDIT2**: As a workaround until this got fixed. you can at least press `TAB` to temporary jump to function signature and view the correct one.

**EDIT3**: I finally reproduced the error with a minimal example:

```
(let ((tag (car (semantic-fetch-tags))))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (semantic-format-tag-summarize tag nil t))
    (buffer-string)))
```

Eval the above code in a file with a pointer. For some reason, when the buffer string is returned, characters like `*` or `&` is deleted. Maybe it should be escaped when ``semantic-format-tag-summarize` returns tag string? I already reported this issue to CEDET maintainer.

**EDIT4**: This bug was fixed with commit [9ea601e](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/9ea601ec45210fb1a20309b710afc74a0a301353). The problem is solved.

Comment: I was looking at the code for `semantic-ia-show-summary`. It calls `semantic-format-tag-summarize` as well. However, its output correct says `const char* fileName`. So, this doesn't sound like a `semantic` issue.

Comment: Interesting. Helm uses the same thing but it returns string with missing info.

Comment: The difference is that `semantic-ia-show-summary` retrieves tags from `semantic-analyze-interesting-tag`, while Helm retrieves from `semantic-fetch-tags`. Probably the two tag formats are inconsistent?

Comment: I thought so too and stepped through the results of it with `edebug`. They looked identical, by comparing the output they wrote to the `*Messages*` buffer. I tried to manually call `semantic-format-tag-summarize` with that output but that gave the same result as `helm` does. I am guessing some information is getting lost in serializing the EIEIO object?

Comment: Another workaround is that you can replace `semantic-format-tag-summarize` with `semantic-format-tag-abbreviate`. It will show you abbreviated form of tags, i.e. no type information, but at least it does not show false information as currently is.

Comment: @Pradhan I finally reproduced the bug with a minimal example.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks. Guess will have to wait for the CEDET developers.

Comment: @Pradhan I fixed this bug and made a PR [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/pull/777). It is not a bug, but a behaviour of `semantic-format-tag-summarize`.

Comment: @Pradhan The bug is fixed in `helm-semantic` now.

Answer (score 1):

I've just patched
[`moo-jump-local`](https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args#moo-jump-local)
to properly handle `const char* fileName`.
It seems that semantic can't currently parse top-level references. Although it parses them
in the arguments lists, as you can see here: [image: moo-jump-local]

Comment: Nice. I wonder if `moo-jump-local` can be used in other languages that Semantic supports, i.e. Emacs Lisp, Python...? If not, then I will use this command only for C/C++ buffers and the old `helm-semantic-or-imenu` for others. EDIT: Seems like it's possible but very rudimentary.

Comment: The goto function of https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy
is pretty advanced for Elisp, Clojure, Common Lisp and Scheme.
For instance, you get dedicated tags for `defgeneric` or `global-set-key`.